# Want to hide a video when it's played by using jquery hide with delay

Tags: jquery, video, hide, delay, fade

I'm having some trouble getting my code working as I want to.

I have a video which play's if I press enter, using mousetrap etc. etc, I'll show in code below. I wish for the video to fadeout when it's over with jquery delay and fadeout, but it does not seem to be working.

Here is my code:

```
Mousetrap.bind('enter', function () {
    document.getElementById('starting').click()
});
```

And:

```
function playPause() {
     var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
     if (myVideo.paused)
         myVideo.play();
     else
         myVideo.pause();
}
```

This is my html-code:

```
<video id="delete" src="app/filmer/takeoff.mp4" width="1366" height="768"></video>

<a id="starting" href="javascript:playPause();"></a>
```

And this is how I'm trying to fadeout the video:

```
$('#starting').click( function() {
    $('#delete').delay(5000).fadeOut();
});
```

The video starts when I press enter, but it does not fadeout, why is that? I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#delete').bind('ended', function() {
   $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: dude, could you create a fiddle or put your link here?

Comment: Mousetrap may not trigger a keyboard event rather emulates a keyboard event, try triggering a custom event.